# cassandra query with data parameter failing

Tags: ruby, cassandra, datastax-ruby-driver

I'm using ruby-driver to connect to cassandra, when I tried to execute the SQL with parameters it keeps failing, because it doesn't recognize "date" as valid.

Is there a proper way to do this?

I'm doing something like this:

```
sql = 'select event_id, event_name, event_date from events where event_date = ?'
event_params = ['2017-03-18']
connection.execute(sql, arguments: event_params)
```

This returns an error:

```
Cassandra::Errors::InvalidError: Expected 4 byte long for date (10)
```

is there a way to validate this parameter as a `Date` instead as a `string`?

my schema is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE events (
  event_id bigint,
  event_date date,
  title text,
  PRIMARY KEY (event_id, event_date)
);
```

Comment: looking at documentation it seems you have to use `arguments:` instead of `parameters:`

Comment: yep, sorry, mistake when writing the post.

Comment: i think you must use a `Cassandra::Date` instead of a string

Comment: Well, seems that the problem is that `ruby-driver` is up-to-date with cassandra.
the problem is that the type `Date` is not defined here: https://github.com/datastax/ruby-driver/blob/master/lib/cassandra/util.rb#L174

So I cannot pass a `Date` nor a `String`